# Pretty database structure

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I'm currently designing my game's database - and I'd like it to be as pretty as possible. Below you'll find some

```
Database Game {

//The ID of the game (unique)
int id

//First player data
varchar firstPlayerName
int firstPlayerSessionID
varchar firstPlayerIP

//Second player data
varchar secondPlayerName
int secondPlayerSessionID
varchar secondPlayerIP

//The opponent type, 0 is default (against the "computer") while 1 is against another player
int type

//The size of the game, default: 3
int size

}
```

(Excuse the format, it's just a mashup intended for myself only)
I'm mainly looking for suggestions on the "Player-part" - I guess it's okay the way it is right now, but what if there would be more than 5 players? Way to messy if you ask me.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a separate Players table, and associate the two tables with a third table (Game_Players) based on the ID of the player and the game.

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate all the game elements in diferent relationed tables?

Having a separate table for players, another for the game's settings, and so on.

That way, it would be simpler to organize the diferent aspects of the game, making it easier to change the games elements and easier to add new elements too.